# Error in the sentence "I am waiting for a phone call from John at three o'clock"?

Tags: error

What is the error in the following sentence?

> "I am waiting for a phone call from John at three o'clock"

is it about 'am waiting' being wrong. and that 'have been' is to be used due to  time clause.

Comment: Can you give us some context? Does the question say what time it is now?

Comment: What makes you think there's an error in it?

Comment: sorry no context thing... it's a find-the-error question asked in the exam

Comment: What's the topic the question is supposed to test you on? (:

Comment: @Au101 nothing. i went for No-Error option :P  but according to the answer key it is there in the "I am waiting for" part... ?

Comment: @user2684291 could be anything, it wasn't the exercise on particular topic, so i cant say anything about it....  the exam is supposed to test THE general understanding of English Language...

Comment: There's nothing, in general, wrong with "I am waiting for" and you can certainly be waiting for a phone call

Comment: @KhurafaatiJaat There is no error. If you receive a down-mark, that is _their_ error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's odd to say you will be waiting for something that is scheduled to happen at a specific time.  *Waiting for X* typically implies you do not know when X will happen exactly.  If you do know when X will happen exactly, the word to use is *expect*:  "I'm expecting a phone call from John at three o'clock.". *Expecting* means something is likely to happen at a given future time.

I have faint memories of reading in a Spanish-English dictionary noticing that hope, wait, and expect were all the same word *esperar.*

Comment: Part of the no-context issue is that "waiting" **isn't** completely impossible... "Why haven't you gotten back to me about that email I sent you this morning?" - "I'm waiting for a phone call from John at three o'clock"... meaning, "I'm waiting to reply until after I talk to John"...

Comment: owww.. got it, thanks... i guess you can't reason about this thing.. i'll just have to accept it.. :)

Comment: So what would you say to your mum when she phoned you up and asked what you were doing while you were waiting on a platform for a train that was on time and which you knew full well when it was coming. I'd say, 'I'm waiting for the train." By the way, I'm not trying to pick holes in your answer, it sounds like that's probably what the examiner had in mind, but I think it's quite a bad question, and I'm not sure I really observe a rule like that. I'm very much more likely to use "waiting for", rather than "expecting" in all cases, unless I'm talking about a birth :P

Comment: yeah..  well, i guess this question isn't totally appropriate to be asked as a find-the-error question.  it might be legit under the sentence-improvement section only [we get that too, with possible options :)]...   hell i would have made it correct that way... with the options... ;)